# Null check in DB singleton

Tags: java, jdbc

I have written one DB singleton class to provide single database connection and I am accepting the connection in another class what if it is null I have to null check condition please explain
Tell me the best practice

```
public class DBSingleton {
    private static final DBSingleton ONLY_ONE = new DBSingleton();
    private Connection connection = null;
    private DBSingleton() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "username","pwd");// SQLException
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static DBSingleton getInstance() {
        return ONLY_ONE;
    }

    public Connection getcon() {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

**another class**

```
private Connection con = DBSingleton.getInstance().getcon();
```

Comment: Unsure what you are asking - How to write a Singleton?

Comment: I have written DB Singleton class to provide single db connection what if it is null

Comment: why don't you throw an exception?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to open a database connection in the constructor of a singleton.  This implies the connection could be perpetually open, way past when you are done using it.

Comment: you'd probably want to hide that rds link in your code sample.

Comment: @smithagowda Whenever object create "connection" would be assign surely.

Comment: @Tim, I think he's trying to create a simple connection pool, in which case connections are reused so it's ok to leave them open. I would still expect to see more connections, not just one though.

Comment: @dsp_user That would make some sense, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
public class BDConnection {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BDConnection.class);
private static Connection connection = null;

public static Connection getConnection() {
    if(connection == null){
        createConnection();
    }
    return connection;
}

private static void createConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName(ImportExportFilesUtils.getResourceMessage("driver.name")).newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ImportExportFilesUtils.getResourceMessage("database.test.url"), ImportExportFilesUtils.getResourceMessage("database.test.username"),
                ImportExportFilesUtils.getResourceMessage("database.test.password"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Cannot load the driver for ojdbc", ex);
    }
}

public static void closeConnection() {
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Cannot close the connection with the database", e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I should not close

Comment: He asked for a Singleton Connection to a database. I've posted to him a singleton way to connect to a database.

Comment: you have a public method to initialize the resource... not a singleton... rather... just a way to get a `connection to a database`